# Is there a way to undo Mocha stubbing of any_instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-mocha

Within my controller specs I am stubbing out valid? for some routing tests, (based on Ryan Bates nifty_scaffold) as follows :-

```
it "create action should render new template when model is invalid" do
  Company.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(false)
  post :create
  response.should render_template(:new)
end
```

This is fine when I test the controllers in isolation. I also have the following in my model spec

```
it "is valid with valid attributes" do
  @company.should be_valid
end
```

Again this works fine when tested in isolation. The problem comes if I run spec for both models and controllers. The model test always fails as the valid? method has been stubbed out. Is there a way for me to remove the stubbing of any_instance when the controller test is torn down.

I have got around the problem by running the tests in reverse alphabetic sequence to ensure the model tests run before the controllers but I really don't like my tests being sequence dependant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manually configure RSpec.

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  ...

  # == Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  # config.mock_with :rspec
end
```

Also, remember that Rspec provides its own methods to mock an object. Use the RSpec API or you won't be able to benefit from library abstraction.
http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/message_expectations.html

Comment: Although the solution is correct, the explanation is not. Mocha does not detect RSpec, but when the RSpec configuration is set as described, RSpec invokes Mocha at appropriate points.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue but not using `Rspec` but normal `Test::Unit`, actually `ActionController::TestCase`.

The defined expectations are keeping alive among the tests.

Is there any clue how can I reset my *expectations* between tests?

- Ruby: 1.9.2
- Rails: 3.0.3
- Mocha: 0.9.10

**Updated**: I have solved this with the `unstub` Mocha method: http://mocha.rubyforge.org/classes/Mocha/ObjectMethods.html#M000009

Answer (score 1):

Does your spec_helper contain

```
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :mocha
end
```

With that rspec should tear down mocks between tests.