# Is there a way to undo Mocha stubbing of any_instance in Test::Unit

Tags: ruby, testing, mocking, stub, ruby-mocha

Much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697168/is-there-a-way-to-undo-mocha-stubbing-of-any-instance), I too am using Ryan Bates's nifty_scaffold. It has the desirable aspect of using Mocha's [any_instance](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/classes/Mocha/ClassMethods.html#M000001) method to force an "invalid" state in model objects buried behind the controller.

Unlike the question I linked to, I'm not using RSpec, but Test::Unit. That means that the two RSpec-centric solutions there won't work for me.

Is there a general (ie: works with Test::Unit) way to remove the any_instance stubbing? I believe that it's causing a bug in my tests, and I'd like to verify that.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As it happens, Mocha 0.10.0 allows [unstubbing on any_instance()](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/ObjectMethods.html#unstub-instance_method).

```
str = "Not Stubbed!"
String.any_instance.stubs(:to_s).returns("Stubbed!")
puts str.to_s   # "Stubbed!"
String.any_instance.unstub(:to_s)
puts str.to_s   # "Not Stubbed!"
```

Answer (score 4):

Mocha does not provide such a functionality. However you can implement it yourself.

The first thing we should know about `mocha` is that `mocha` actually replaces the original methods when you stub them. So in order to be able to restore these methods later, you must keep a reference to the former ones. It can be easily achieved by: `alias new_method old_method`.
It must be done **before** mocking the `old_method`.

Now, to unmock a method, you only need to `alias old_method new_method`.

Consider the following code:

```
class A
    def a
        true
    end
end


class TestA < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_undo_mock
        a = A.new
        A.class_eval {alias unmocked_a a}

        A.any_instance.stubs(:a).returns("b")
        assert a.a, "b"

        A.class_eval {alias a unmocked_a}
        assert a.a, "a"
    end
end
```

Comment: Excellent. This looks like something that could be added/monkeypatched into Mocha too.

Comment: I've never felt the need for this functionality, but there is a ticket - http://floehopper.lighthouseapp.com/projects/22289-mocha/tickets/69-allow-unstubbing-of-methods if you want to lobby for the change. It would be great if you have some examples of why you'd want to use it.

Comment: I have added unstubbing functionality - Mocha::ObjectMethods#unstub - see http://mocha.rubyforge.org/classes/Mocha/ObjectMethods.html#M000009

Comment: Mocha now has this; see my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all your stubs/expectations in one go, then you can do that using mocha_teardown (eg. call self.mocha_teardown).

May be a little bit destructive in this case, however.