# mocking in Ruby: mocks are sticking around between tests

Tags: ruby, mocking, rr

I'm using RR as the mocking framework for a personal project of mine.  I've been using it to mock the new method for some classes and when I run the tests they pass fine, but when I run ALL of the tests I run into a problem where it seems like the "new" methods are still returning the fake results, even when in a different test file.  Is there a way to turn off the stubbing of the new method manually?  What am I missing here?

Thanks for the help,
Alex

I've tried putting this code into my app and it breaks the app, and.... doesn't fix the above problem.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rr
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocks are replacing your old methods. Once a method is replaced by your mock it will never be normal again unless you using precautions.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894331/is-there-a-way-to-undo-mocha-stubbing-of-any-instance-in-testunit/2896885#2896885) thread. I explained there how one can undo Mocha mocks using simple `alias`.

Answer (score 1):

RSpec's mocks are torn down automatically between tests. However, when you configure RSpec to mock with another library, you still have to use it through the [RSpec mocking API](http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/message_expectations.html).